# When do suffixes "-able" or "-ible" translate with "-bar" vs. "-lich"?

Tags: grammar, translation, suffix

We can not simply translate the suffixes *"-able"* or *"-ible"* with *"-bar"* as there seem to be many examples where *"-lich"* is used instead.

> avoidable - *vermeidbar*
>   vulnerable - *verwundbar*
>   bootable  - *bootbar*
>
> reliable - *verlässlich*
>   movable - *beweglich*
>   comprehensible - *verständlich*

Sometimes both variants exist:

> usable - *benutzbar*, *nützlich*
>   solvable - *lösbar*, *löslich*
>   bearable - *tragbar*, *ertäglich*

Sometimes this may even change on negation:

> avoidable -*vermeidbar* 
>   inavoidable - *unvermeidlich*

Are there any rules that help me to decide when using the one or the other?

Comment: Good question. As a side note I think *movable* would be better translated *bewegbar* whereas *beweglich* is more like *agile*.

Comment: As musiKk already noted, the two variants, if both exist, don't necessarily have the same meaning. *Solvable*, to add another example, translates both to *lösbar* and *löslich*, but in German, *löslich* would only translate back to *soluble*, i.e. a term from Chemistry, whereas *lösbar* is a term you apply to a problem of sorts, e.g. in Mathematics. I am not aware of any convenient, useful rule capable of resolving all those problems with *-bar* and *lich*.

Comment: @Hackworth: Yep, I thought about *solvable* too. Same goes for *usable*: *nützlich* is *useful*.

Comment: Pardon, `solvable` := löslich? Solvable coffee? `usable` := nützlich? I would translate `nützlich` to `useful`, not `usable`.

Comment: If 2/3 of the examples don't fit, I don't call it 'not always', but 'rarely'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suffix **-bar** is *often* used with **transitive verbs**:

> Suffix, durch dessen Anfügen an den Stamm eines meist transitiven Verbs ein Adjektiv abgeleitet wird [...] *(from [German Wiktionary: -bar](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-bar))*

For example:

> avoidable - vermeidbar  → **vermeiden** (transitive)
>
> vulnerable - verwundbar → **verwunden** (transitive)
>
> reliable - verlässlich → **verlassen** ([in this case] intransitive)
>
> movable - beweglich → **bewegen** (intransitive)

A verb is transitive if you can use it for *something* or *someone*:

> Jemanden sehen, etwas lösen, etwas haben

And intransitive if you can't:

> Laufen, scheinen, dünken

Note that this is really just a rule-of-thumb; it doesn't necessarily work 100 per cent of the time (though I can't think of a verb where it fails now). :)

The English -ible versus -able seems to work differently:

> The form -ible has the same senses and pronunciation. The choice between the two is somewhat idiosyncratic, but in general, -ible is used in forms derived from Latin verbs of the second, third, and fourth conjugations, and in a few words whose roots end in a soft c or g, while -able is used in all other such words, particularly those formed from Latin verbs of the first conjugation and those that come from French or from Anglo-Saxon (Old English). *(from [Wiktionary: -able](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-able))*

Note tohuwawohu's great comment:

> ... For example, a locomotive can move "itself", but i (personally) can't move it myself, so it's beweglich but (from my point of view) not bewegbar. See also here and here.

Comment: I'd like your examples of transitive and intransitive verbs a lot better if you can really use them with either _-lich_ or _-bar_. Aber _laufbar_ oder _lauflich_ ist mir nicht geläufig `:-)` (_Dünken_ ist sowieso ein etwas seltsames Beispiel, denke ich.)

Comment: `bewegen` is a good example. You can use it as transitive or as intransitive verb, with corresponding adjectives: `bewegbar` in a transitive sense - you can move something, and `beweglich` as intransitive - something is able to move. For example, a locomotive can move "itself", but i (personally) can't move it myself, so it's `beweglich` but (from my point of view) not `bewegbar`. See also [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_bar) and [here](http://canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/bar.html).

Comment: How can ‘bewegen’ be an intransitive verb? If it can move *itself*, it is still transitive. Considering the examples, it would be a bit better to speak of reflexive versus non-reflexive usage.

Comment: @Debilski: you're right, it seems i mixed up transitivity with reflexivity. It's obvious since [one of the pages i cited](http://canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/bar.html) describes the semantics of -bar for both transitive and intransitive verbs. Hmm, another disadvantage of comments: you can't edit them any more after a certain amount of time... `:-|`