# Ist "kumulierbar" ein schweizerischer Begriff?

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe auf Gutscheinen (in der Schweiz öfter als *Bon* bezeichnet) gelesen, sie seien *nicht mit anderen Rabatten kumulierbar*.

Siehe auch einen [Artikel im Konsumentenmagazin K-Tipp](http://www.ktipp.ch/artikel/d/kaufrecht-sind-gutscheine-kumulierbar/).

Anscheinend weiss mein Duden (25. Auflage) nichts über *kumulierbar*. Ist dieser Begriff ein Helvetismus und wird deshalb vorwiegend in der Schweiz benutzt?

Comment: Dein Duden kennt aber [kumulieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kumulieren), und 'kumulierbar' ist nur davon abgeleitet. Das Wort ist jedoch als bildungssprachlich bzw. Fachsprache eingestuft und wird daher in aller Regel im normalen Sprachgebrauch nicht verwendet. Der Duden definiert das Wort nicht als "landschaftlich" oder gar "schweizerisch". Der Begriff kommt auch eigentlich aus dem Wahlrecht, die obige Verwendung ist damit auch eigentlich etwas merkwürdig, da *kumulieren* etwas differenziert zu *kombinieren* definiert ist.

Comment: @Em1: Nicht nur aus dem Wahlrecht (im Gegensatz zu _panaschieren_, das in der Tat darauf beschränkt ist). Kumuliert wird auch im Versicherungswesen (Risiken), in der Buchhaltung (Zahlen aus verschiedenen Zeitperioden), [im Immisionsschutz](http://www.fnp.de/rhein-main/kreise_of_gross-gerau/Der-Fluglaerm-kumuliert-sich;art688,251399).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wenn wir eine Google Suche auf deutsche oder auf Schweizer Seiten eingrenzen, dann ergeben sich folgende Ergebnisse für "kumulierbar":

- Deutsch:    54 300
- Österreich: 16 400
- Schweiz:   137 000

Dieser Unterschied wird angesichts der relativ kleineren Anzahl von Webpräsenzen aus der Schweiz noch deutlicher. Insgesamt sind die Suchergebnisse aber spärlich, der Begriff scheint nur selten gebraucht zu werden.

Die großen renommierten Zeitungen Die Zeit, Spiegel und Süddeutsche Zeitung kennen den Begriff nicht. Im Archiv der FAZ findet sich nur ein einziger Treffer zur Suche nach "kumulierbar". Allerdings scheint es auch bei der Neuen Zürcher Zeitung ein kaum verwendeter Begriff zu sein (nur zwei Treffer).

Dies alles zeigt, dass es sich um eine selten vorkommende Adjektivierung des Verbs [kumulieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kumulieren) mit Suffix *"-bar"* handelt. Es wundert also kaum, dass dieses Wort keinen Einzug in ein Wörterbuch gefunden hat.

Dennoch wird "kumulierbar" auch in Deutschland verwendet, vor allem im Zusammenhang mit Bauförderungsmaßnahmen:

> - Die Förderung von Anlagen zur Nutzung erneuerbarer Energien als Einzelmaßnahme ist nicht möglich, da eine Förderung über das BAFA erfolgt. Kumulierbar mit dem Programm “KfW-Energieeffizient sanieren / Sonderförderung” (431). Nicht kumulierbar mit anderen Förderprogrammen von Bund und Ländern und mit der Kreditvariante “Energieeffizient sanieren” (151/152). <sup>[Planungsbüro Thiele](http://www.pb-thiele.de/fordermittelzusammenfassung-einfamilienhauszweifamilienhaus/)</sup>
> - **BAFA-Förderung und KfW jetzt kumulierbar!** Seit 1. März 2013 lohnt sich der Austausch der alten Heizung gegen eine Pelletsheizung für Sanierer gleich doppelt: Denn ab sofort kann der KfW-Kredit mit den Zuschüssen des Marktanreizprogramms (MAP) kombiniert werden. <sup>[ÖkoFen](http://www.pelletsheizung.de/de/news/news/action.view/entity.detail/key.778.html)</sup>

Und auch im Kontext von Rabattaktionen wird man in Deutschland fündig:

> - Einmal pro Benutzer einlösbar und nicht mit anderen Aktionen kumulierbar. <sup>[Lidl Druckservice](http://www.lidl-druckservice.de/)</sup>

Vielleicht ist es nur eine Frage der Zeit, bis das Wort "kumulierbar" wieder verschwindet oder so häufig wird, dass es eines Wörterbucheintrags würdig ist. Heute wird es offenbar häufiger in der Schweiz gebraucht, auch wenn es dadurch noch kein Helvetismus ist.

Zur Suffigierung mit *"-bar"* siehe auch folgende Frage:

- [When do suffixes "-able" or "-ible" translate with "-bar" vs. "-lich"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/when-do-suffixes-able-or-ible-translate-with-bar-vs-lich)

Comment: Der Spiegel kennt aber *kumulieren* und natürlich in Verbindung mit Wahlen. Da steht's im Vergleich mit der nzz 400 zu 200 für Deutschland. FAZ ist vergleichbar mit nzz, die Süddeutsche schneidet erbärmlich ab.

Comment: @Em1 kumulieren != kumulierbar - ich denke es geht hier darum, ob und wie häufig man das Suffix -bar anhängt.

Comment: Und ist dann akzeptieren != akzeptierbar?

Comment: @Em1: Ja. Ich weiß nicht, ob _akzeptierbar_ regional verbreitet ist, aber für mich ist es kaum akzeptabel. _Akzeptieren_ dagegen ist ein übliches Wort.

Comment: @chirlu Mein Punkt ist ein anderer. Irgendeine Endung muss man anhängen. Du kannst vllt auch "kumulabel" draus machen, aber ich denke jeder stimmt mir zu, dann doch eher "kumulierbar". Und ein Wort das generell wenig und wenn dann nur in Zusammenhang mit bestimmten Kontexten Verwendung findet, da findet man halt auch wenig Treffer für eine Abwandlung, vor allen Dingen "seriöse Quellen" ersparen sich solche Worte und formulieren es in besserem Deutsch. "Akzeptierbar" hat übrigens weniger Treffer als "kumulierbar", steht aber im Duden. :)

Comment: @Takkat... die Recherchemaschine ;)... Respekt für die Arbeit, die du da reinsteckst

Comment: @Em1: selbstverständlich ist "kumulierbar" nicht das selbe wie "kumulieren", es handelt sich schließlich um verschiedene Wortgattungen (Adjektive/Verben) aber die Verwandschaft ist nicht zu leugnen. Auch ich kenne "akzeptabel" als geläufige Adjektivierung des Worts "akzeptieren", und möchte beitragen, das Youtube bei Sprache "Deutsch" (es bietet keine Regionalversionen an, daher gehe ich von Hochdeutsch mit flächendeckend verständlichen Begrifflickeiten aus) seine Aufrufstatistiken als "kumulativ" und "täglich" darstellen kann.

Comment: @rimrul Das klingt auch viel besser, also z.b. *kumulative Rabatte sind nicht gestattet*

Comment: @EM1 Ich persönlich bevorzuge "Nicht mit anderen Rabatten oder Aktionen kombinierbar".

Answer (score 6):

Ja. Du erkennst es leicht daran, dass eine Google-Suche für "kumulierbar" auf Schweizer Seiten mehr Ergebnisse liefert als die für deutsche Seiten. Das ist normalerweise ein untrügliches Zeichen für eine regionale Besonderheit. Im normalen Deutschen ist dieser Begriff erlaubt, man würde ihn in diesem Zusammenhang aber eher nicht benutzen. Hier sagt man "kombinierbar".